# How to send large video on a channel using a telegram bot?

Tags: python, api, telegram-bot

Here's my code:

```
from telegram import Bot
bot = Bot(
    token="XXX"
)

def send_video(chat_id, video_path):    
    print(f"Sending '{video_path}' to {chat_id}...")
    bot.send_video(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        video=open(video_path, 'rb'),
        timeout=10000,
        supports_streaming=True,
    )
    print("Video sent!")
```

Using this method, I can only upload videos up to 50mb, what should I do to upload larger sized videos?

Edit: you can do that, I just don't understand how: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server

Comment: `10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.` So there's no option to send files > 50mb

Answer (score 1):

you can use large video files with using, pyrogram client.Here this documentation located at https://docs.pyrogram.org, use send_video or send_document as well